# Is my Norwegian forest cat too heavy?

Tags: cats, weight

I have a Norwegian forest cat. He is three years old; will be four in June. He just went for a vaccination/checkup and weighed in at 7.3 kg. The vet said he should be 6kg but they don't see a lot of Norwegian forest cats.

Is 7.3kg too heavy? He doesn't look fat under all that fur.

Also, should we be feeding him according to his activity? Some days he sleeps/rests most of the day and other days he wakes us up to play in the early morning/night.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to check if your cat is overweight is to compare to something like this:

[image: Cat weight chart from the Las Vegas Pet Weight Loss website]

([Source](http://lasvegaspetweightloss.com/))

and talk to a veterinarian specializing in cats, preferably cats with weight problems. If you are uncertain about the knowledge of your regular veterinarian, seek out a second opinion.

If he does have a weight problem, you will have to put him on a diet. Now, I don't have anything backing this up, but a diet based on activity seems uncertain. How do you know what he is doing all day? Now, it could probably work, but an easier solution is just to reduce the amount of energy he gets.

It is *very important* that a cat doesn't get starved while dieting. You cannot just calculate the required energy intake for the goal weight and go from there. A cat must lose weigh slowly. A cat that isn't fed properly can develop [fatty liver which is *very dangerous*](http://www.veterinarypartner.com/Content.plx?A=1455).
So if you are unsure about the dieting process, contact your veterinarian!

Comment: OK answer but doesn't address the Norwegian Forest Cat part- he is likely still growing.

Answer (score 2):

Norwegian forest cats do tend to be bigger than average. If your vet didn't mention any weight problems at the last visit, then the cat is probably fine. Definitely ask about the cat's weight at the next vet visit. You can also ask your vet to show you how to check the weight yourself (e.g., where to feel for the ribs). Different cats have different shapes, so it isn't that easy to tell if they are overweight just by looking.

I wouldn't adjust your cat's diet based on each day's activity. I would only adjust it based on the cat's weight (per the vet's advice) and age/average level of activity.